# Cloudinary custom_coordinates not working for hybrid app on ios

Tags: ios, hybrid-mobile-app, cloudinary

Here is the code I am using to crop images via upload to cloudinary:

```
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', imageFile);
    formdata.append('upload_preset','banner_preset');
    formdata.append('cloud_name', GALLERY.cloudiName);
    formdata.append('custom_coordinates',[coords.x, coords.y, coords.w, coords.h]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', GALLERY.cloudURI, true);
```

this works find on android, and all browsers including Safari. But when I try to upload via the hybrid app on ios custom coordinates do not work. I get no error just the coords are not  working.

Here is the request data:

[image]
[image]

Here is the response I get:

[image]

Not sure why this doesn't work on only Hybrid app on IOS. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm guessing that screenshot has been edited to remove your cloud name but is it also removing the boundary for the `custom_coordinates` parameter? Is there any difference in the POST data between the iOS version and the others?

Comment: You are right I did hide that. The custom_coordinates are 0,1191,2268,866.  I did just double check from browser Safari (Safari browser works fine) and its exactly the same. I did notice their coordinates (response) are not suppose to be the same as I posted but the coordinates of the new image.

Comment: The issue is with IOS and getting the dimensions of the uploaded file. They appear to be reversed. So rather than having a width of 4032 its showing 3024. I'm using var image = new Image() then image.height and it's wrong.